# Render view on backend and execute client side scripts

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, export-to-excel

So I am exporting to excel. The way I do this is I render views on the backend, and then write an excel file using the string of the HTML that the view generated. Problem is, this one view I want to generate is just some blank tables/columns until the client side code executes. It's being rendered, but none of the Jquery is executing so nothing is populated when I export, and I get a blank export. Here is the view:

```
    <table id="exposureTableBTS">
        <tr>
            <td id="headerBTS" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tableBTS" />
            <td id="graphBTS" />
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#exposureTableBTS").bubble({ width: 400, title: 'Exposure:', backgroundColor: '#ffffff'  });

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/GetExposure ",
                dataType: "json",
                data: GetJSONForID(),
                success: function(data) {
                      CreateTableFromPoints(data.expsosure);
                }
            });


    function CreateTableFromPoints(data)
    {
        $("#tableBTS").html(CreateExposureBodyTable(data));
        $("#headerBTS").html(CreateExposureHeaderTable(data));
    }

    function CreateExposureGraph() {
             $.ajax({
                url: "/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/ExposureGraph",
                data: GetJSONForID(),
                error:function(x,e){
                    if(x.status==0){
                        alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                    }else if(x.status==404){
                        alert('Requested URL not found.');
                    }else if(x.status==500){
                        alert('Internel Server Error.');
                    }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                        alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                    }else if(e=='timeout'){
                        alert('Request Time out.');
                    }else {
                        alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
                    }
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $("#graphBTS").html(data);
                }
            });
        }

});
</script>
```

Here is my backend code:

```
protected string RenderViewToString()
        {
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                var view = new WebFormView(_viewPath);
                var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<Model>(_model);
                var viewCxt = new ViewContext(_context, view, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
                viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
```

For pages that get rendered without using Javascript to render or update anything, this works fine. But how do I get this page to render to string AFTER the Javascript is executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready() {
    $("body").hide();
})
```

And then...

```
function CreateExposureGraph() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        complete: function() {
            $("body").show();
        }
    });

}
```

Just an idea.

Comment: It was just about the only thing I could really think of... hide the body until your last client script executes then call $("body").show() when appropriate. The window load event may not be the appropriate time. If your code is executing synchronously, call the show at the end; otherwise if your rendering is reliant on asychronous XHRs then I'm not sure there will be an easy option.

Comment: The only thing is the code is never opened within a browser so I dont know how to get the JS to run.

Comment: Call .show() during the complete callback from your last AJAX call. I assume the one that requires the time to render the HTML is CreateExposureGraph so I've updated my answer accordingly. Complete occurs after success/error handlers. [Docs for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) have more information about when the complete callback is invoked etc.

Comment: Then call it from the complete callback of whatever asynchronous rendering call is responsible for altering the content of your page, i.e. "/Extranet/mvc/Indications.cfc/GetExposure" or so on.